# Grouping an already grouped result set

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code in my PHP script:

```
$query = "
select
MIN(test.id), 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ' ', test.virtualno,' <br>' SEPARATOR ' '),
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ' ', test.courseno,' <br>' SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM test 
group by test.courseno
";
```

Now this returns the following result,
But I would like to get the following result instead:
[current & wanted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ1Vk.jpg)

My table structure is:
[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD4hV.jpg)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please provide your table structure

Comment: IMO you can use YaLinqo on application layer

Comment: Try with `group by test.courseno, test.virtualno`

Comment: I tried with group by test.courseno, test.virtualno but that returns each row separately.

Comment: Can you explain (in english rather than code) what you are trying to do. Best I can work out is that you want all the courseno grouped together than share the same combinations of virtualno along with the min id for each courseno.

Comment: ignore the id if we can , basically since the 3 virtualno repeat in both of the courseno I want them to be grouped so they show 1 time but both courseno to be grouped as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the id (and the formatting with HTML breaks but that should be easy to sort out), this should do it:-

```
SELECT sub0.all_virtualno, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sub0.courseno)
FROM
(
    SELECT courseno, GROUP_CONCAT(virtualno ORDER BY virtualno) AS all_virtualno
    FROM test
    GROUP BY courseno
) sub0
GROUP BY sub0.all_virtualno
```

Gets the courses and all the grouped virtualno. The from that groups the courses where the grouped virtualno are the same

Comment: Thanks Kickstart, it's working. My real DB has 12 columns the columns that mimick courseno display the same as courseno which is fine, but how do I add another column that mimicks the virtualno ? Right now this 2nd column displays only the first line which is grouped hence only 1 item is shown not all 3 like virtualno column.

Comment: Ok I got it to work with all my columns thanks to your solution Kickstart. Thanks again.